# flutter How to edit the index in PageView in another widget and main index change automatic?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

How I can change the `PageView` index in another widget, while applying it on the main page?

```
PageView.builder(
        reverse: true,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int position) {
          return PageViewWidget(
            displayZekr: _displayZekr,
            position: position,
          );
        },
        controller: s,
        itemCount: _displayZekr.length,
      ),
```

Comment: You need to explain your question better. You can format your code with three grave marks at the beginning and end: \```dart \```

Answer (score 0):

You should do 5 steps:

1. make your widget a `Stateful Widget` so, you can change the state of it (in your example page index)
2. create a global int for page index : `int pageIdx = 1;`
3. create a function for changing page index:

```
void changePageIndex(){
   setState((){pageIndex++;});
}
```

4. call this function wherever you want
5. use the global index as an active page!

Comment: where do I put this function in order to be able to call it? Above the @override build method? How do I call this method from another widget?